# Xamarin Iconize IconTabbedPage Example

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

Can someone provide an example of how to use the IconTabbedPage in Iconize, preferably in Xaml? I have an IconTabbedPage with IconNavigation pages as children, all defined in Xaml. I then set the Icon property of the subpages by specifiying the font awesome name (“fa-home”). I tried to set the title as well, but neither of these will render the icon. I have search (a lot) for examples of the IconTabbedPage but couldn’t find any in Xaml. Additional bonus if you can provide an example of how to use the icons in a list cell context action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can take a look on Sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize/Samples/Iconize.FormsSample)

```
[\[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)\]
namespace Iconize.FormsSample
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            var tabbedPage = new IconTabbedPage { Title = "Iconize" };

            foreach (var module in Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.Modules)
            {
                tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Page1
                {
                    BindingContext = new ModuleWrapper(module),
                    Icon = module.Keys.FirstOrDefault()
                });
            }

            MainPage = new IconNavigationPage(tabbedPage);
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}][1]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! That works, I just wanted to try to define in XAML instead!

Answer (score 2):

Looking into @Niklas Code, you can create a tabbed page with a base class that inherits from IconTabbedPage , then your xaml will look like this.

```
<icon:IconTabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:icon="clr-namespace:Plugin.Iconize;assembly=Plugin.Iconize"
        ....
       >
 <icon:IconTabbedPage.Children>
    <ContentPage Title="Build" Icon="md-build">

    </ContentPage>
</icon:IconTabbedPage.Children>
```

I hope it will help somebody